# Problem with changing button text content

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm making a battleship game in Javascript and I have a problem with a function that changing button text content. I want to do that when the user click the button the text content of the button changes.

```
function changePosition(eventBtn){
if(eventBtn.target.textContent=='perpendicularly'){
    eventBtn.target.textContent='horizontally';
}
else{
    eventBtn.target.textContent='perpendicularly';
}}
```

But when I click on the button nothing changes. I think the problem is with the else statement because when I delete this statement all work.

Comment: Can you please add your HTML, or provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your code seems fine - I tried it out in CodePen and it worked. You need to share a bit more information :) Here's my Codpen https://codepen.io/cdimitroulas/pen/QWdrMBg

Comment: Probably depends on if the button is a button or an input - don't think text content works on an input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are adding the listener to the button appropriately.

```js
function changePosition(event) {
  if (event.target.textContent === 'Perpendicularly') {
    event.target.textContent = 'Horizontally';
  } else {
    event.target.textContent = 'Perpendicularly';
  }
}

document.querySelector('.direction').addEventListener('click', changePosition);
```

```html
<button class="direction">Perpendicularly</button>
```

In regards to the following statement:

> *But when I click on the button nothing changes. I think the problem is with the else statement because when I delete this statement all work.*

Your event may be firing twice. It could be calling your event listener twice, effectively reverting the change it just made to the text.

---

### Suggested improvement

Magic strings are bad, and I would recommend the use of enumerable values instead.

```js
const Direction = {
  PERPENDICULARLY: 'Perpendicularly',
  HORIZONTALLY: 'Horizontally'
};

const changePosition = event => {
  event.target.textContent =
    event.target.textContent === Direction.PERPENDICULARLY
      ? Direction.HORIZONTALLY
      : Direction.PERPENDICULARLY
};

document.querySelector('.direction').addEventListener('click', changePosition);
```

```html
<button class="direction">Perpendicularly</button>
```

Comment: I added listener appropriately

Comment: @Tsuso Please show how you added it in your code above. You will need a minimal example that runs.

Comment: I solved this problem. It turned out that I place the listener in a loop.